# Beamer: animate package and overlay

Tags: beamer, animate

I am trying to get an animation running in beamer with the following setup:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[]{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,trees,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,backgrounds,calc,shadows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
 \usetikzlibrary[shadings]
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{default}
\useoutertheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=3pt,text margin right=3pt}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.jpg,.png}
\graphicspath{ {./Pictures/} }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \animategraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,keepaspectratio,autopause,autoresume,autoplay,loop]{0.5}{pp_}{1}{54}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.9\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node at (2.5,-0.6) [rectangle,draw=white,fill=black,fill opacity=0.7,
   rounded corners, text width=0.9\textwidth, text height=0.9\paperheight] (aa) {};
   \node at (aa) [rectangle,text width=0.8\textwidth, text=white] () {
     \only<1>{\calligra \blindtext}
     \only<2>{\calligra \blindtext}
     \only<3-4>{\calligra \blindtext}
   };
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{columns}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to have an ongoing slide(picture) show in the left column while going through some text in the right column. Since the text is rather big it must be shown consequtive blocks. This is achieved via the "only" command. Now "only" causes beamer to generate, in this example, four slides. The problem is that when one proceeds to the next slide the animation in the left column restarts at frame 0. It occurs that every frame is runnig its own animation. But what I want is a single ongoing animation in the left column invariably of the beamer slide I am currently are.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: If you mean that there as a wrong bracket in the tikz path ..... I have changed it.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I thought it is already from the frame code obvious what I mean and it might be a very common "problem". However, I changed the code but to compile one must set it's own graphic directory. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Beamer` frames with overlays and `animate` generated animations are problematic. (See [↗Bugs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#section.9) section in the `animate` documentation.)

As correctly observed by the OP, `Beamer` produces multiple PDF pages with independent animations in the case of slides with overlays. The current frame number and the playing state, direction and speed would have to be transferred from one animation to the next upon page change, in order to give the illusion of a single animation running.

This *can* be achieved using the [↗JavaScript interface](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#section.7) of `animate`. The necessary code is executed during Page-Open and Close events of hidden PDF annotations.

**Edit:** To further enhance overlay awareness of animations, the `beamer` command `\alt<>{}{}` can be used to reserve space on "silent" slides (note the `draft` option in the alternative clause). If this is not desired, the animation can just be put into `\only<>{...}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{animate}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \let\myPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\putBeforeAnim#1{%
  \myPdfAnnot{1ex}{1ex}{0pt}{%
    /Subtype/Screen/F 2%
    /AA <<%
      /PC << % exec on page-close
        /S/JavaScript /JS (
          try{
            var #1CurFrame  =anim.#1_\thepage.frameNum;
            var #1CurSpeed  =anim.#1_\thepage.speed;
            var #1PlayingFwd=anim.#1_\thepage.isPlaying&&anim.#1_\thepage.playsFwd;
            var #1PlayingBwd=anim.#1_\thepage.isPlaying&&(!anim.#1_\thepage.playsFwd);
          } catch(e){}
        )
      >>
    >>%
  }%
}

\def\putAfterAnim#1{%
  \myPdfAnnot{1ex}{1ex}{0pt}{%
    /Subtype/Screen/F 2%
    /AA <<%
      /PO << % exec on page-open
        /S/JavaScript /JS (
          try{
            anim.#1_\thepage.frameNum=#1CurFrame;
            anim.#1_\thepage.speed=#1CurSpeed;
            if(#1PlayingFwd){ anim.#1_\thepage.playFwd(); }
            if(#1PlayingBwd){ anim.#1_\thepage.playBwd(); }
          } catch(e){}
        )
      >>
    >>
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.25\textwidth}
  Bla, bla\dots

  \alt<2->{%
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \putBeforeAnim{myAnim}%
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \begin{animateinline}[
        label=myAnim_\thepage,
        width=\linewidth,loop,
        controls={play,stop,speed},
        buttonsize=1em
      ]{1}
        \multiframe{54}{i=1+1}{\Huge\framebox[1.4em][r]{\i}}
      \end{animateinline}%
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \putAfterAnim{myAnim}%
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  }{%
    \phantom{\begin{animateinline}[
        draft,
        width=\linewidth,loop,
        controls={play,stop,speed},
        buttonsize=1em
      ]{1}
        \multiframe{54}{i=1+1}{\Huge\framebox[1.4em][r]{\i}}
    \end{animateinline}}%
  }

  More bla, bla\dots
\column{0.75\textwidth}\tiny
  \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \item \kant[1]
    \item {\Huge\color{alert} Animation appears!} 
    \item \kant[3]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot. I had already a guess in that direction, eg. write the frame number somewhere when autopausing and read it when starting. However, I am almost illiterate when it comes to javascript. So thanks for providing the code.