# Beamer: combine overlay with autoplaying video's

Tags: beamer, overlays, video

I want to create a slide with latex beamer that lets appear 2 or more video's one at a time, such that

- when I press space a 1st time, the 1st video appears and starts to play automatically
- when I press space a 2nd time, the 2nd video appears next to the 1st one and starts to play automatically. The 1st video is continuing playing as if I hadn't touch any button
- etc.

The issue is similar to [Beamer: animate package and overlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384890/beamer-animate-package-and-overlay) . However, when using the javascript provided in this answer together with the 'autoplay' option of the \animate command, all previous video's restart each time a new video appears.

Any suggestions to resolve this problem? Possibly answering one of the questions below resolves it.

Is there a way to invoke the start of a video in animate with a single latex code snippet, something like the following?

```
\only<2>{
  start playing the video that appears
}
```

Is an adaption of the javascript at [Beamer: animate package and overlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384890/beamer-animate-package-and-overlay) possible? (I cannot write javascript)

Are other beamer packages for latex beamer more appropriate to get this working properly?

Comment: The package for the inclusion of videos is `media9` of @AlexG

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. However, I do not succeed to play video's from a media9-generated pdf, neither with acrobat-reader for linux nor windows. I used the 2nd example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer for this test.