# Combine beamer code with MSPowerpoint presentation

Tags: beamer, video, powerpoint

I am used to make slides with latex beamer. However, certain features are not possible or too difficult with latex beamer but they are possible with MSPowerpoint. An example of this is the more advanced usage of video embedding ([Beamer: combine overlay with autoplaying video's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586618/beamer-combine-overlay-with-autoplaying-videos)). For this particular issue, it is easy to do it with MSPowerpoint.

This makes me end up with a video-embedded pdf for most slides at the one hand and a pptx video embedded presentation for a particular slide at the other hand. I want however only one presentation. Can I combine these?

Most likely solution seems to me that latex beamer can compile to pptx, pptm or ppt directly such that I can merge the presentations in MSpowerpoint. The otherway around, converting the powerpoint to a pdf and then merge, seems rather a bad idea because the features of MSPowerpoint I use are difficult to embed in pdf.

Are there any latex packages or programs that I can use in order to properly combine my latex slides and MSpowerpoint slide in a single format (most probably ppt)?

Comment: What is your question :) you seem to have solved already

Comment: I don't think you can mix and match easily that way: Chose the appropriate tool and make it work. If that's PowerPoint on occasion, why not? (My needs are simple, but I have at times simply paused my slide presentation to show an external video to the audience.)

Comment: I think your question cannot be solved and should be closed (although I understand why you want it :)).